Spotipy (python) functions run forever with OAuth
    import requests
    import json
    import spotipy
    from credentials import CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, REDIRECT_URI
    from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth


    # auth
    print('starting auth')
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id=CLIENT_ID, redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, scope='playlist-modify-public user-library-read'))
    print('finished auth')

    taylor_uri = 'spotify:artist:06HL4z0CvFAxyc27GXpf02'

    print('searching')
    results = sp.artist_albums(taylor_uri, album_type='album')
    print('done searching')
    albums = results['items']
    while results['next']:
        results = sp.next(results)
        albums.extend(results['items'])

    for album in albums:
        print(album['name'])

    results = sp.artist_albums(taylor_uri, album_type='album')

the line above leaves the code hanging, i have tried many other functions but will just load forever...

